# Visual Studio Solution Explorer Locks Up

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2005 w/ TFS where, from time to time, the Solution Explorer will stop responding to interaction.  Instead it does the beep, like I'm trying to click on a parent window with a modal dialog visible, but there isn't one.  The only thing I've found to do so far, is to restart VS, but that's kind of a pain because our solution is rather large.  And it's not even a guarantee... it might happen again when I load the solution.

I was curious if anyone else has had this problem and knows of a better solution that restarting VS until it goes away.

[Edit: 6-11-2010] I've since moved over to VS 2008 and haven't had this problem since.

Comment: I use task manager to minimize and maximize and the lockup seems to go away.  I have noticed a connection to my monitor layout, I have a third monitor centered between the top two.  When I reconfigure into a strip it resolves the issue.

Comment: Third answer fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 7):

If VS Editor lockdown is accompanied by creation of **Setup.exe** process that never finishes (visible in the task manager), then this is an issue with Microsoft Office 2007 components.

The solution that has worked for me - reinstalling Microsoft Office 2007. [More details](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/5/12/visual-studio-2008-locks-or-freezes-in-aspx.html).

Comment: +1 I had the same problem, fixed, thanks. Although for me running the Setup.exe that was spawned worked fine.
http://mattfrear.com/2010/03/09/visual-studio-2008-sp1-locks-up-after-installing-office-2010-rc/

Comment: +1 I don't even have Office 2007, but I have COmmunicator 2007 and LiveMeeting 2007 -- running the Setup.exe that was spawned fixed it.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\Office Setup Controller\SETUP.EXE

Comment: This problem appeared for (in VS 2008) me only ofter I tried to use the html design view. After that every time I edited a html or aspx file the Setup.exe process was created. I tried all the recommended fixes and was only successful after re-installing Office 2007 (MS Word only). This could be a result of uninstalling Office 2007 when I upgraded to Office 2010 64bit.

Comment: See Dave W. solution below.  It's the same fix essentially, but the "Repair" option (if it works) is less time intensive than a complete reinstall.  Again, see "Dave W" solution elsewhere for this post.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2005, the modal dialogs that pop up remember their position relative to 0,0 on the Windows virtual desktop. If you change your multimon configuration, for example removing a monitor, and the popup dialog restores itself to a position that no longer is a visible part of the virtual desktop, you can have a modal dialog existing off screen. If you enter this situation again, try hitting alt-spacebar to pull down the System menu of the window, and then press M for move. Then press one of the arrow keys and the dialog's position will then bind itself to the mouse. You can then bring the modal dialog back on screen.

This bug was fixed in VS 2008 SP1.

Comment: I have VS 2008 SP1 and this bug still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this was a common problem in Visual Studio 2005, a background thread would like Visual Studio and no let anything happen.  Then a little icon would should up in the status bar that basically said "Visual Studio is Working Be patient."  This happened to me whenever I started the document explorer for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems like this with different parts of VS 2005, but they had more to do with network drives that were no longer accessible and IntelliSense refreshing.

I made sure to unmount any unused network drives and disable IntelliSense since I'm using Visual Assist anyway using this method:

http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5550

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with VS2008 9.0.30729.1. SP and once I used Alt+Space, then M, then dragged the model window into view VS2008 was thereafter able to remember where I wanted this model dialog to be displayed.

Note that Google was not able to find this page, but Bing was!

Answer (score 1):

My OS is 64bit.  I had office 2007 installed.  I uninstalled it and installed office 2010.  Then this problem started occurring.  I ran the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\Office Setup Controller\Setup.exe" application using the repair option and the issue is resolved.  A colleague of mine had the same issue for the same reason and the same fix resolved the issue for him also.

Comment: This worked for me! I found this hint a little late, after I tried to repair VS2008 and then later...uninstall and reinstall VS2008 (and then VS2008 SP1). (None of the VS2008 reinstall stuff worked). Plus ONE! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try unbinding your solution from source control. You can use the command line TFS tool ("tf") to do the same actions and it should prevent VS from freezing up due to high latency connections / drops, to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Also, a very large document store will slow down the Team Explorer significantly.. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

My Visual Studio 2008 would lock up every time I was entering the Designer mode editing an aspx file.

My solution was to reinstall .net 3.5 with sp1 and it seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Visual Studio 2008 (and specifically after installing MVC framework). My resolution was to install the .Net 3.5 SP1 Family update, reinstall Visual Studio through add/remove, and reinstall MVC framework... hopefully that helps someone - because the issue was really ANNOYING.

Answer (score 0):

If solutions start behaving badly one of the first things I would try is if deleting the .suo file helps. This file contains information about the current designer and Window state (and more).

Deleting this allows reopening the solution just like when it was just checked out from source control, without designer crashes etc.

If you have some add-in problems, running 'devenv.exe /resetskippkgs' might help. (This re-enables add-ins that have been disabled after previous errors)

Answer (score 0):

I just started getting the same problem with VS 2008 after a clean install of Office 2010 Pro Plus.  Alt-Space-M-arrow keys isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have had Souution Explorer lock up after undocking it and moving it onto a second monitor.

Wierdly, Solution Explorer still responded when I changed the file I was working on but did not allow me click in the window itself.

This was fixed by selecting **Window > Reset Window Layout**