# Problem after installing ASP.NET MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

- Installed ASP.NET MVC
- Created Project
- About 2 minutes into project (not even running / building / debugging)
- Visual Studio 2008 will no longer take focus from the mouse.
- Click on visual studio - seems like there is a modal open somewhere.
- Windows + D... no modal
- Can't see VS2008 in alt tab
- Only way to get it back is task manager.
- Happens with multiple solutions / projects...alawys ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

1. Press Alt + Space
2. If you see a menu appear that has Move as an option, select Move
3. Press any arrow key
4. Move your mouse around.
5. Hopefully a modal dialog will appear.

Comment: good idea, but no dice - ugh
note: it wont let me right click on the Visual Studio instance in the application bar. Also it doesnt appear any other apps are running...

Answer (score 0):

I really really hate to ask this, but did you try rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to another related post that may be of use.

[Visual Studio Solution Explorer Locks Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227230/visual-studio-solution-explorer-locks-up/739054#739054)